# How can i remove from recycler view if the condition is met?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

So I'm retrieving a data from firebase then I want to delete an item if the condition is met not on my database just to remove it from the `recyclerview`

Here is my code:

```
for (DataSnapshot roomSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
     minmax.clear();
     DataSnapshot priceSnapshot = roomSnapshot.child("promos").child("regular").child(ym).child("price").child(guest);
     for (DataSnapshot ds : priceSnapshot.getChildren()) {
          minmax.addAll(Collections.singleton(Integer.parseInt("" + ds.getValue())));
          minmax.removeAll(Collections.singletonList(0));
          if(minmax.isEmpty()){
             mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition()); 
          }else{
           int min = Collections.min(minmax);
           holder.hPrice.setText("Start From " + String.valueOf(min));
          }
      mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all you should not call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` inside a loop .

Comment: mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());  will remove your item.

Comment: @ADM where should I put `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` ?

Comment: @VijaySinghChouhan nope it does not still displaying

Comment: Try to remove from  list as well.

Comment: The list nothing to do to populate the `recyclerview` I'm using `firebase-ui` this code is just a query inside the `firebase-ui`